# SimPy Bank Tutorial with users lining up for a specific counter, and being able to leave the line early

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I'm looking at this SimPy tutorial https://pythonhosted.org/SimPy/Tutorials/TheBank.html#several-service-counters and **I am wondering how this could be changed to have customers use the same line but use a specific counter?** **And as a further modification, what if they did not have to wait to be at the front of the line to get to a specific counter?**

Background: I'm trying to simulate a line of people lining up to go to a theatre with set seats.  Everyone has to line up to get into the theatre itself, but not everyone has to wait for the guy in row 5 to be seated if they are in 6 or greater. And everyone has a set seat (much like a "counter" in the example). I really enjoy my local theatre but I am hoping to be able to simulate a much easier way for people to line up and find their seats.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the old documentation for SimPy 2. This is no longer supported. Please refer to the docuemntation of the current version 3 of SimPy: http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/